# Tensorflow model structure is strangely deformed in model.fit()

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn, computer-vision

I was able to confirm (by checking `model.summary()`) that a model with the correct structure was successfully created. However, when `model.fit()` is called, a specific variable (`strides`) is fixed and the model is deformed. The detailed code description is as follows.

First, I made residual block class in ResNet50 by using tensorflow:

```
class ResidualUnit50(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, strides=1, activation="relu", **kwargs):

    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.activation = keras.activations.get(activation)

    self.main_layers = [
        keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, strides=strides, padding="same", use_bias=False),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        self.activation,
        keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 3, strides=1, padding="same", use_bias=False),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        self.activation,
        keras.layers.Conv2D(filters * 4, 1, strides=1, padding="same", use_bias=False),
        keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        ]

    self.skip_layers = []

    if strides > 1:
        self.skip_layers = [
            keras.layers.Conv2D(filters * 4, 1, strides=strides, padding="same", use_bias=False),
            keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        ]


    def call(self, inputs):
        Z = inputs
        skip_Z = inputs
        for layer in self.main_layers:
            Z = layer(Z)

        out_dim = Z.shape.as_list()[-1]

        if strides > 1:
            for layer in self.skip_layers:
                skip_Z = layer(skip_Z)
        elif out_dim != inputs.shape.as_list()[-1]:
            skip_Z = keras.layers.Conv2D(out_dim, 1, strides=1, padding="same")(skip_Z)
            skip_Z = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(skip_Z)

        return self.activation(Z + skip_Z)
```

And I made ResNet50 as below.

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 7, strides=2, input_shape=[32, 32, 3], padding="same", use_bias=False))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Activation("relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))

prev_filters = 64

for filters in [64] * 3 + [128] * 4 + [256] * 6 + [512] * 3:
    strides = 2 if filters / prev_filters == 2.0 else 1
    model.add(ResidualUnit50(filters, strides=strides))
    prev_filters = filters

model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D())
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
```

But when I tried to train the model with cifar10, I got an error as below. In `model.summary()`, I was able to confirm that the stride changed well and a model with the correct structure was created. However, when `model.fit()` is called, strides are fixed to 1 in all layers. I don't understand how the model structure changes like this.

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="nadam", metrics=["accuracy"]) 
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test)) 
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

error message:

```
Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 8 for '{{node sequential_18/residual_unit50_176/add}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](sequential_18/residual_unit50_176/batch_normalization_649/FusedBatchNormV3, sequential_18/residual_unit50_176/batch_normalization_3/FusedBatchNormV3)' with input shapes: [?,4,4,512], [?,8,8,512].
```

How to fix the error?